# Return a mirror binary tree in python

Tags: python, binary-tree

I am trying to figure out a way to write a function that takes a binary tree and returns the mirror of it. I am guessing it will be done recursively but I can't figure out the algorithm.

EDIT: I saw solutions to a problem similar to this however they were not in python, I did not deal with a programming language other than python so I did not understand the solution

Thank you

Comment: Yes I saw that post before I posted, the solution is written in a programming language that I don't understand since I have only dealt with python

Comment: in python: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15325281/mirror-binary-search-tree

Comment: One of the [answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4366310/2089675) in the duplicate does not rely on any programming language and should be easy to translate to any language

Answer (score 1):

lets say you have a tree that looks like this `((2,1),((6,5),(4,3)))` a recursive algorithm that flips all node's would look like this:

```
def flip(t):
    return(t if type(t)!=type(()) else(flip(t[1]),flip(t[0])))
```